# how to accelerate the convergence of fixed point iterations

Tags: roots, arithmetic, programming, fixed-points

I'm calculating two sequences:

$x_{n+1} = (a - x_n)/2$

and

$x_{n+1} = a - x_n/2$

The goal is to divide $a$ by 3 (both $a$ and $x_n$ are whole numbers). I don't have access to general division, only division by powers of 2. Both sequences converge very slowly. Could you give a hint as to how I might accelerate the rate of convergence and how to wisely select $x_0$?

I reformulated the equations so I could use Newton's method, but it requires general division and does not work that well with whole numbers anyway. This applies to most other root-finding methods as well and something complex is out of the question anyway.

The solution already exists in form of 6502 [code](https://codebase64.org/doku.php?id=base:8bit_divide_by_constant_8bit_result), but the programmer opted not to document the method (s)he was using to accelerate convergence. There exists an online 6502 [emulator](http://txt3.de/).

EDIT:
In the end I decided to expand formula 2:

$x_{n+2}=a-x_{n+1}/2=a-(a-x_n/2)/2=(a+x_n/2)/2$

This is how we obtain the result of 2 iterations after 1 iteration and now I use this formula instead of the previous one. If 6502 code uses this approach is unclear to me.

another formula I came up with is:

$y_{n} =  (x_{n+1} + x_{n+2}) / 2 = 3/4a - x/8$

which converges even faster (lol).

Comment: The referenced code seems to use something like multiplication with the reciprocal instead, which is a totally different beast

Comment: it looks like a fixed-point calculation to me because of the constant $x_0$. I suspect Aitken's method.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Multiplicative_inverses_of_numbers_and_power_series

Comment: @metamorphy thank you, very instructive, but what I had in mind was $x_{n+1}=(x_n^2 + a^2/9)/(2x_n)$, for example, but you could recast the problem in other ways as well. I'm pretty sure the reciprocal is not being sought, even though that is one possible way to divide through multiplication. The fixed point is being corrected IMO.

Comment: but, in this case, the result is known to be positive, so, I guess, this is the correction that could be applied.